# Making a new instantiated prefab as a child for existing GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image]

I've been searched about how to make these fruit to move as the basket movement if it collided with it, and I've been found that if I want to perform this I've to let these fruit to be a child to the basket game object .. for example :

```
 banana.transform.parent = basket.transform;
```

banana and basket each of them of type "GameObject" ...

BUT unfortunately this way didn't work !! and I don't know why ??

So now I need to know if it is possible to destroy the banana if a collision with the basket happened and instantiate a new banana in the basket as a child at run time ?!!

I need to try this stupid way because I've tried all the other ways and nothing worked :(

Comment: `banana.transform.parent = basket.transform;` should work. You should figure out why it isn't working. Maybe you are still moving the object downwards even after it has been caught?

Comment: @Calvin : Maybe you are still moving the object downwards even after it has been caught? ...> yes I think so ,, but how to disable this ?

Comment: That depends: what's making it move in the first place? If it's a component attached to the banana, you can disable that component.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Extension method

```
public static void FindParentAndAttach(this GameObject go, string parentName)
{
    GameObject memberParent = GameObject.Find(parentName);

    if(memberParent.Equals(null))
    {
        memberParent = new GameObject();
        memberParent.name = parentName;
    }

    go.transform.parent = memberParent.transform;

}
```

You can then attach any gameobject to a parent by supplying its name, if the name doesnt exist, it creates a empty gameobject at the root level with that name.

```
gameObject.FindParentAndAttach("Your Parent Name");
```

Comment: This would work, but it's not a very robust solution, and it's pretty slow compared to alternatives. I think the comments on the question are right, the person who asked the question should figure out why setting the parent isn't working (and maybe post more information on the script, and the setup of transforms in the scene)

Answer (score 0):

Like that you can try

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    Transform child =Instantiate(cubePrefab,new Vector3(i * 1.2f,0,0),Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
    child.parent = Gobj2.GetComponent <Transform>();
}
```